# DEV C ++ Error: expected declaration before '}' token

Tags: c++

What does this mean?
My program goes like this: (NOTE: The line that has the error was the line coming before case 2.)

```
case 1:
{
cout<< "C * H * E * M * I * S * T * R * Y \n\n";
cout<< "1) What is the valence electron configuration of Selenium (Se)?\n\n";
cout<< "\na) 1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2\n\n";
cout<< "\nb) 1s2 2s2 2p2\n\n";
cout<< "\nc)4s2 4p4\n\n";
cout<< "\nd) 1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p6 4s2 3d10 4p6 5s2 4d10 5p5\n\n";
cout<< "Enter your answer:\n";
cin>> answer;

if (answer == 'c')
{
    cout<<"Your answer is correct. Please press the enter key to proceed to the next question.\n\n";
}
else
    cout<< "The correct answer is C. Please press the enter key to proceed to the next question.\n\n";

getch ();
}

getch ();
cout<< "2) Which element yields the biggest atomic radius?\n\n";
cout<< "\na) Ca\n\n";
cout<< "\nb) Xe\n\n";
cout<< "\nc) B\n\n";
cout<< "\nd) Cs\n\n";
cout<< "Enter your answer:\n";
cin>> answer;
if (answer == 'd')
{
    cout<< "Your answer is correct. Please press the enter key to proceed to the next question.\n\n";
}
else
    cout<< "The correct answer is D. Please press the enter key to proceed to the next question.\n\n";

getch ();
}

cout<< "3) Name the ionic compound K2 Cr2 O7\n\n";
cout<< "\na) potassium chloride\n\n";
cout<< "\nb) potassium carbonate\n\n";
cout<< "\nc) potassium chromite\n\n";
cout<< "\nd) potassium chromate\n\n";
cout<< "Enter your answer:\n";
cin>> answer;
if (answer == 'd')
{
    cout<< "Your answer is correct. Please press the enter key to proceed to the next question.\n\n";
}
else
    cout<< "The correct answer is D. Please press the enter key to proceed to the next question.\n\n";


getch ();
}
}
case 2:
{
cout<< "G * E * O * M * E * T * R * Y \n\n";
```

The error, as noted in the title is `expected declaration before '}' token` at the line noted in my opening paragraph.

Comment: Most likely it means your "{", "}" don't match. I'd recommend to use an editor that can understand C syntax and highlights matching curly brackets.

Comment: It means that your code is a monolithic mass of deeply indented blocks. Refactor.

Comment: @Jim Balter and his upvoters. Come on! Have your read OP's code? This is obviously not a professional coder asking, so adapt your remarks. Yes, this would be bad code for a pro, but if this works as expected, it's already an achievement.

Comment: Now, to be constructive, you could suggest storing questions and answers in arrays (or maybe std::vector) and iterating (using for loops) over them. That would cut the amount of code (and bug/typo risks) nicely.

Comment: Please post full code next time, as well as compiler errors. While we were able to figure out the likely source of your problem, we probably would not have been able to help had the issue been complex.

Comment: Fixing your code indentation will allow you to spot errors more easily.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want this:

```
if (answer == 'd')
{
    cout<< "Your answer is correct. Please press the enter key to proceed to the next question.\n\n";
}
else
    cout<< "The correct answer is D. Please press the enter key to proceed to the next question.\n\n";


getch ();
}
}
```

To look like this:

```
if (answer == 'd')
{
    cout<< "Your answer is correct. Please press the enter key to proceed to the next question.\n\n";
} else {
    cout<< "The correct answer is D. Please press the enter key to proceed to the next question.\n\n";
    getch ();
}
```

It looks like you lost track of your scope immediately following the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two }'s right before the `case`. Where are the corresponding {'s? Especially the last `else` looks a bit lonely.

Answer (score 0):

After I reformatted your code so it would display tolerably on the website, the errors stand out pretty clearly.

I would recommend, when you use brackets around the `if` clause, also use them around the `else` clause:

```
 if (foo) {
     /* ... */
 } else {
     /* ... */
 }
```

Leaving off the brackets is quite fine if both cases are just one statement. And while there's no requirement about putting brackets around both clauses if only one *needs* them, I have found plenty of bugs around `if` statements with brackets around only one path. It's surprising. :)

On a further note, a text editor with bracket-matching capabilities would be a huge assistance. Many editors will highlight brackets that aren't properly nested, and some provide a key to jump between them quickly. (In `vi` and clones, the `%` key will bounce between `()`, `{}`, `[]` and `<>` pairs. Very handy.)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a superflous "}" after each getch:

```
 getch ();
 }
^^^
```